# Cross referencing tables in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

[schema db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIyYr.png)

I have an ads table which has 1:n relationship to an ad_address and an ad_copies tables.
Then there are the categories and the subcategories tables where the category has 1:n relationship with the subcategory table and the subcategory table has a 1:n relationship with the ads table.

So the subcategory table has a reference field called id_categories and the ads table has a reference field id_subcategories.

The ads_address and ads_copy tables both have an ad_id field.

Now I've been busy trying to get data from a json file (a previous database) into a new rails app. I've discovered that the schema of the this previous database contained a separate table which has all the reference fields together, i.e., the id_categories, id_subcategories and ad_id fields.

```
create_table "rel_anuncio", primary_key: ["id_anuncio", "id_categoria", "id_subcategoria"], force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
  t.integer "id_anuncio", null: false
  t.integer "id_categoria", null: false
  t.integer "id_subcategoria", null: false
  t.integer "orden", null: false
end
```

Here's how I seed my ad records (the table names of the json file are Spanish):

```
if row['name'] == "categorias"

row["data"].each do |record|
  @cat = Category.create!(
    user_id: user.id,
    name: record["nombre"]
  )
end

elsif row['name'] == "subcategorias"

row["data"].each do |record|
  @subcat = Subcategory.create!(
    category_id: @cat.id,
    name: record["nombre"]
    )
end

row["data"].each do |record|
  @ad = Ad.create!(
    user_id: user.id,
    subcategory_id: @subcat.id,
    [..]
    )
end
```

I get an a `"NoMethodError: undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass"` for the line `"subcategory_id: @subcat.id"`, because there's no subcategory_id to link to the ad record I realized, because the subcategory_id is in a different table.

Now I know there must be a way to cross reference these id's within the hash so that you can see which id numbers belongs to which record. For example, if you have id_subcategory: 3, then this must belong to the ad record with name "Wok Restaurant" with id: 4.

I want to seed the correct category and subcategory to my ad records in my rails app.

More in general I'd like to know how someone would handle importing a json file of a database with a different schema than your own database in a railsapp.

Here's sample of the json file (only first line of each table):

```
[
  {"type":"header","version":"4.7.9","comment":"Export to JSON plugin for PHPMyAdmin"},
  {"type":"database","name":"qqx486"},
  {"type":"table","name":"anuncios","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id":"1","empresa":"Wok Bufet Gran Oriente","tel":"971 315 964","fax_principal":"","movil_principal":"","email_principal":"","web":"","facebook":"","horario_v_principal":"","horario_i_principal":"Abierto mediod\u00eda y noche","direccion_principal":"C\/ Jos\u00e9 Zornoza Bernabeu, 15, L2","poblacion_principal":"EIVISSA","activo":"no","tam_anuncio":"completa","twitter":"","link":"no","general":"no","isla":"ibiza","subtitulo":"","comentario":"","modificacion":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","promo1":"0","promo2":"0","instagram":"","tel2":"","tel3":"","tel4":"","movil2":"","movil3":"","movil4":""},
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"anuncios_direcciones","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id":"157","id_anuncio":"1","direccion":"C\/ Sant Jaume, 114","poblacion":"SANTA EUL\u00c0RIA","telefono":" 971 336 274","fax":"","movil":"","email":"","horario_i":"","horario_v":""},
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"anuncios_gps_a","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id":"1","id_anuncio":"22","lat":"38.9082100","lon":"1.4289690","accuracy":"10"},
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"anuncios_gps_b","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id_anuncio_direcciones":"459","id_anuncio":"1068","lat":"0.0000000","lon":"0.0000000","acc":"0"},
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"anuncios_textos","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id_anuncio":"1","id_idioma":"1","descripcion":""},
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"caracteristicas","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id":"1","nombre":"Jard\u00edn"},
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"caracteristicas_textos","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id_caracteristica":"1","id_idioma":"1","titulo":"Jard\u00edn"},
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"categorias","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id":"1","nombre":"RESTAURANTES Y ALIMENTACI\u00d3N","color":"","activo":"si","bdd":"guias","orden":"1","promoI":"0","promoF":"0","islas":"3"},
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"categorias_porsi","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id":"1","nombre":"RESTAURANTES Y ALIMENTACI\u00d3N","color":"","activo":"si","bdd":"guias","orden":"1","promoI":"0","promoF":"0"},
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"categorias_textos","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id_categoria":"1","id_idioma":"1","titulo":"RESTAURANTES Y ALIMENTACI\u00d3N","clave":""},
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"enlaces","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id":"1","nombre":"Digital Grafic Ibiza","web":"http:\/\/www.bestof.org"}
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"enlaces_textos","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id_enlace":"1","id_idioma":"1","descripcion":"Empresa en Ibiza"},
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"idiomas","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id":"1","nombre":"Espa\u00f1ol","self":"es","color":"F00"},
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"inmuebles","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id":"1","ref":"Roca Llisa","id_inmobiliaria":"91","tipo":"piso","estado":"","zona":"Santa Eulalia","sup_vivienda":"0","sup_parcela":"0","sup_terrazas":"0","plantas":"0","dormitorios":"3","banyos":"2","piscina":"no","parking":"no","entorno":"","precio":"380000","activo":"si"},
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"inmuebles_textos","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id_inmueble":"1","id_idioma":"1","titulo":"Roca Llisa","descripcion":"Apartamento d\u00faplex, cocina, sal\u00f3n\/comedor, 2 terrazas, preciosas vistas al mar, piscina y paddle tenis comunitarios."},
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"playas","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id":"1","nombre":"PLATJA DE TALAMANCA","longitud":"900","orientacion":"SE","google":"https:\/\/www.google.es\/maps\/place\/Cala+Talamanca\/@38.9132677,1.4565971,16z\/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x1299414743b6e207:0xe628e2f006419c0d","cnauticas":"38\u00b055\u201900.8\u201dN 1\u00b027\u201916.8\u201dE","municipio":"Eivissa","activo":"si","orden":"0"},
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"playas_textos","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id_playa":"1","id_idioma":"1","breve":"Playa de arena fina a pocos minutos a pie de Marina Botafoch y a 1,8 km. del centro de la ciudad de Eivissa.","descripcion":"Se trata de una bah\u00eda cerrada, poco profunda, ideal para el ba\u00f1o sin ning\u00fan peligro y muy bien protegida por los vientos. Gran variedad en restaurantes, bares y chiringuitos, incluso algunos est\u00e1n abiertos todo el a\u00f1o. Existe una pasarela de madera a lo largo de casi toda la playa. Se realizan cursos para iniciarse en deportes n\u00e1uticos como el catamar\u00e1n, kayak y windsurf.","servicios":"Restaurantes y chiringuitos \u2013 Hoteles \u2013 Alquiler de tumbonas y sombrillas \u2013 Deportes acu\u00e1ticos \u2013 Duchas y WC p\u00fablicos \u2013 Acceso minusv\u00e1lidos \u2013 Parking gratis \u2013 Transporte p\u00fablico.","llegar":"En coche, en autob\u00fas de l\u00ednea regular o en una barquita que va del puerto de Eivissa hasta Botafoch, y de ah\u00ed puede ir andando llegando en pocos minutos."},
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"promo","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id":"1","idioma":"1","empresa_id":"943","titulo":"10% Descuento","tituloCR":"8","tituloCG":"8","tituloCB":"8","tituloFS":"20","texto1":"7 horas de fiesta y mucho m\u00e1s","texto1CR":"255","texto1CG":"255","texto1CB":"255","texto1FS":"20","fondo1CR":"255","fondo1CG":"43","fondo1CB":"227","fondo1CA":"90","texto2":"","foto1":"","foto2":"","code":"C\u00f3digo: Isla Blanca","tiempo1":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","tiempo2":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","activo":"2","status":"1","orden":"1"},
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"rel_anuncio","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id_anuncio":"814","id_categoria":"7","id_subcategoria":"81","orden":"37"},
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"rel_guias","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id_anuncio":"7","id_guia":"1"},
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"rel_inmuebles","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id_inmueble":"1","id_caracteristica":"2"},
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"subcategorias","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id":"1","id_categoria":"1","nombre":"Restaurantes","color":"","activo":"si","orden":"1","promoI":"0","promoF":"0","islas":"3"},
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"subcategorias_porsi","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id":"1","id_categoria":"1","nombre":"Restaurantes","color":"","activo":"si","orden":"1","promoI":"0","promoF":"0"},
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"subcategorias_textos","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id_subcategoria":"1","id_idioma":"1","nombre":"Restaurantes","clave":"restaurantes, pizzer\u00edas, los productos de alimentaci\u00f3n, almuerzos, cenas, fiestas, c\u00f3cteles, cocktails, comen, comer, beber, las cocinsa mediterr\u00e1neas, barras, comedores, comiento, sitios para comer, restaurantes especializados en bistecs, el alimento japon\u00e9s, comida japonesa, el alimento espa\u00f1ol, comida espa\u00f1ola, el alimento italiano, comida italiana, parrillas, la cocina francesa, el alimento alem\u00e1n, comida alemana, comidas, licores, mariscos, el alimento asi\u00e1tico, comida asi\u00e1tica, pescados, mariscos, camarones, gambas, tabernas,"},
    ]
  }
  ,{"type":"table","name":"version","database":"qqx486","data":
    [
      {"id":"32"}
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the original JSON? I can sort-of guess what it looks like from your code, but can't be certain.

Comment: I've edited my question with a sample of the json in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `Ad` & `Subcategory` has a many to many relationship. So `rel_anuncio` is the intermediate table to make the relationship.

As the rows of the json are in different a order than the way you need to create the records.

Instead try to first create the `Ads`, then the `Categories` and the `Subcategories` at the end.

```
json_ads = parsed_json.find { |table| table['name'] == 'anuncios' }
ads = {}

json_ads['data'].each do |ad|
  ads[ad['id']] = Ad.create(
    [... ad fields]
  )
end
```

And the same for `Categories`:

```
json_categories = parsed_json.find { |table| table['name'] == 'categorias' }
categories = {}

json_categories['data'].each do |category|
  categories[category['id']] = Category.create(
    [... category fields]
  )
end
```

Now that you create the `Subcategories` you have the `Hash` with `Categories` to reference them:

```
json_subcategories = json.find { |table| table['name'] == 'rel_anuncio' }
subcategories = {}

json_subcategories['data'].each do |subcategory|
  subcategories[subcategory['id']] = Subcategory.create(
    category: categories[subcategory['id_categoria'],
    [... ad fields]
  )
end
```

And the `rel_anuncio` information will depend on how you implement the relationship.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, the seed worked, id_category has been seeded in the subcategories table. So if I now would like to make a rel_ads table which would take care of the n:n between resp. categories vs. ads and subcategories vs. ads. How would I make the seed.rb fill the rel_ads table?

Comment: Would be similar @OKMantis:

json_relationships = json.find { |table| table['name'] == 'rel_anuncio' }

json_relationships['data'].each do |relationship|
  RelAd.create(
    category: categories[relationship['id_categoria']],
    ad: ads[relationship['id_anuncio']],
    subcategory: subcategories[relationship['id_subcategoria']],
  )
end

Please mark the answer on top as correct, if it solved your problem.

Comment: When I do that I get no errors, but when I look in my console I see that Relationships (I named table that way) is completely empty. Why didn't take anything from rel_anuncio?

Comment: It shows me this:
[1] pry(main)> Relationship.all
  Relationship Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "relationships".* FROM "relationships"
=> []

Comment: ActiveRecord (when I use .create! instead .create) gives me this:
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Subcategory must exist

Comment: I've done this now:
class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ad, optional: true
  belongs_to :category, optional: true
  belongs_to :subcategory, optional: true
end

Comment: [1] pry(main)> Relationship.all
  Relationship Load (2.3ms)  SELECT "relationships".* FROM "relationships"
=> [#<Relationship:0x00007f7f0ce41e88
  id: 1,
  ad_id: 69,
  category_id: 7,
  subcategory_id: nil,
  created_at:
   Sat, 05 May 2018 16:00:10 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at:
   Sat, 05 May 2018 16:00:10 UTC +00:00>,

Comment: Subcategory is still nil. Even when I cut and paste the subcategories table inside json file above the rel_anuncios table. I don't understand.

Comment: json_relationships = parsed_json.find { |table| table['name'] == 'rel_anuncio' }

json_relationships['data'].each do |relationship|
  Relationship.create!(
    category: categories[relationship["id_categoria"]],
    ad: ads[relationship["id_anuncio"]],
    subcategory: subcategories[relationship["id_subcategoria"]]
    )
end

Comment: I found the answer, it was in the subcategories seed => I changed "rel_anuncios" to "subcategorias".